# Why is Nginx truncating the JSON streaming response?

Tags: nginx, gunicorn, flask, grpc, http-streaming

Our stack is `Client(Browser) <-> Nginx Reverse Proxy <-> Webserver(Flask+Gunicorn) <-> Golang gRPC server`

The problem is when the client makes a call to the `/realtimedata` endpoint, Flask then opens the gRPC connection and starts receiving data via a server->client unidirectional stream. It then passes it back to the client. When I run this without Nginx, I get all responses. When running with Nginx, some responses get truncated. For example, if we expect:

```
{
    "source": "serviceA",
    "timestamp": 123456789,
    "data": {
        "1": 24.55667,
        "2": -456.5656,
        ...
        "200": 5.678
    }
}
```

We get

```
{
    "source": "serviceA",
    "time
```

Then

```
        stamp": 123456789,
    "data": {
        "1": 24.55667,
        "2": -456.5656,
        ...
        "200": 5.678
    }
}
```

This would be printed in console.log. I have `proxy_buffering off;` in the nginx configuration otherwise no data makes it to the browser. Not sure how to resolve this issue.

[Here](https://github.com/SSSOC-CAN/nginx_issue) is a minimum, reproducible example.

**UPDATE:**
I've ran the minimum reproducible example with Apache2 instead of Nginx and experiencing the same random truncations.

Comment: What do you mean by "We get [...] and then [...]"?! That you receive all the data anyway? I don't see why that would be an issue.

Comment: I print the response in the console on the browser. So I'll receive for example one half of the response, then the other. But it is an issue because `response.JSON()` yields an error when it's truncated like that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar behavior from Apache(!) breaking up a html file respone from django. It  always broke at the same position without any reason. I finally found that I accidentally did install a mod_wsgi package into Apache from a Python version that did not match the version Apache was calling my app in. Maybe it helps you.

Comment: Hey thanks I'll check that out. I ended up using websockets to solve the issue. The truncating stopped.